# Cannot upgrade to Flutter 3.7.12 from 3.7.7

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upgrade Flutter stable channel from `3.7.7` to `3.7.12`.

The terminal after running `flutter doctor`.

```
fnet34-f72-access:Project user$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-SG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

The terminal after running `flutter upgrade`.

```
fnet34-f72-access:NovadeLite mariaivoneiradjaja$ flutter upgrade
Upgrading Flutter to 3.10.0 from 3.7.7 in /Users/mariaivoneiradjaja/flutter...
Downloading Darwin x64 Dart SDK from Flutter engine d44b5a94c976fbb65815374f61ab5392a220b084...
```

After running `flutter upgrade`, it will upgrade to `3.10.0` and not `3.7.12`. This command does have any parameters in the doc.

Is there a way to specify the version when upgrading Flutter?

Comment: I am upgrading from 3.7.7 to 3.7.12 though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have multiple versions of Flutter installed, you have two great solutions.  The traditional solution is fvm.  The new kid on the block is puro.  Both can be found in the pub.  Puro is interesting because you can go from having no flutter installation to a working flutter installation of any release version directly, without having to first install it the traditional way, and it even updates your path for you.

Update: I have [a nice video on that](https://youtu.be/olqmK-opexA).

Answer (score 1):

According to the official Flutter documentation, if you want to use a specific Flutter version, you may have to download it directly from the [Flutter SDK archieve](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/archive).